# I can't unsertand if .equalTo() works in my framgent

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My query to see if the category is equal to a string is:

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    // All my posts order by category

    Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();

    mPostKey = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CATEGORYV);

    Query viewCategory = databaseReference.getDatabase().getReference("posts");
    viewCategory.orderByChild("category").equalTo(mPostKey);

    return  viewCategory;
}
```

In debug, I have seen that `mPostKey` contains the right string, but this query shows me ALL the posts.

This is my Firebase Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `orderByChild()` or `equalTo()` it returns a *new* query object. So you're now returning the unmodified `DatabaseReference`.

So:

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    // All my posts order by category

    Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();

    mPostKey = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CATEGORYV);

    Query viewCategory = databaseReference.getDatabase().getReference("posts");
    return viewCategory.orderByChild("category").equalTo(mPostKey);
}
```